# Increment variable on page postback and load different pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a property as shown below

```
private int Step
{
    get { return (int)Session["step"]; }
    set { Session["step"] = value; }
}
```

In the `Page_Init` method, I am initializing it as below

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
        Step = 0; 
    }
}
```

In the click event of my save button, I am trying to reload the page as if it was the first time the save button was clicked. If it was the second time the save button was clicked, then redirect to another page.

```
protected override void cmdNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.SaveViewModel();
    Step++;
    if (Step > 1)
    {
        base.cmdNext_Click(sender, args);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); //reloading the page again
    }                 
}
```

The issue is that on the first time the page is reloaded and the `Page_Init` method sets the variable to 0 again so it never goes past through 1. Can someone please tell me how I can load the same page on the first button click and move on to some other page after the second button click?

Thanks

Comment: Check if Session["step"] is null before initializing?

Comment: Did you try `if (!IsPostBack && Step == 0)`? May have to check for the existence of the session variable in the getter, but should work.

Comment: Thanks Guys..checking for null first worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the Session is null before initializing

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if (!IsPostBack && Session["step"] == null)
    { Step = 0; }
}
```